# Check Hbase native extension got WARN [main] lz4.Lz4Compressor: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm running a hbase and hadoop hdfs cluster (3 nodes, running both hadoop and hbase). They were hadoop-3.2.2 and hbase-2.3.6 and jdk 11.0.14 and they weren't stable. After upgraded to hadoop-3.3.3 and hbase-2.4.9, jdk 11.0.15, I want to check Hbase native extension with command:

```
su - hbase -c 'hbase org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeLibraryChecker'
```

I got following warning:

```
[root@node101:~]#su - hbase -c 'hbase org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeLibraryChecker'

2022-06-06 17:47:32,221 INFO  [main] bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-bzip2 library system-native
2022-06-06 17:47:32,224 INFO  [main] zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
2022-06-06 17:47:32,231 WARN  [main] lz4.Lz4Compressor: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.lz4.Lz4Compressor.initIDs()'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'java.lang.String org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.lz4.Lz4Compressor.getLibraryName()'
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.lz4.Lz4Compressor.getLibraryName(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec.getLibraryName(Lz4Codec.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeLibraryChecker.main(NativeLibraryChecker.java:109)
```

java --version

```
openjdk 11.0.15 2022-04-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.15+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.15+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
```

hadoop-env.sh on 3 nodes:

```
grep "^[^#;]" /opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh

export HADOOP_OS_TYPE=${HADOOP_OS_TYPE:-$(uname -s)}
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java))))
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/"
export HADOOP_PID_DIR="/var/run/hadoop"
export HADOOP_LOG_DIR="/var/log/hadoop"
```

hbase-env.sh:

```
grep "^[^#;]" /opt/hbase/conf/hbase-env.sh
export JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java))))
export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/opt/hadoop/lib/native"
export HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS="$HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS -Xms1G -Xmx3G -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=4G"
export HBASE_JMX_BASE="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"
export HBASE_MASTER_OPTS="$HBASE_MASTER_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10101"
export HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS="$HBASE_REGIONSERVER_OPTS $HBASE_JMX_BASE -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10102"
export HBASE_PID_DIR=/opt/hbase
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
export HBASE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/hbase
```

Could you please help me know what causing problem?
I'm sysadmin and don't have many experiences in coding.

Thanks and have a good day
Man Sinh LE

Comment: I could be wrong, but bad idea to use this Java version with HBase? I believe you need Java 8, not higher. Also, if you check through HBase docs (best place here: https://hbase.apache.org/book.html) you will find a table that lists all versions of Hadoop and HBase that are compatible with each other. Try to make sure your versions are OK with each other.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried to use Java 8 but issue still remains.Java 8 ended of life. Hbase and Hadoop are now supporting Java 11. I see my upgraded clusters are running more stable than the old ones but I'm still having the warning.